# Жарити VS смажити?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-russian, росіянізм, дієслова

У [Російсько-українському академічному словнику (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) пише:

> **Жа́рить** – прягти́ (-жу́, -жеш), пря́жити, ***сма́жити***, шква́рити, пекти́; (на жиру) сма́жити, шква́рити.

Отже, згідно з цим словником, *смажити* - це український відповідник російському *жарить*.

Однак у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/smazhyty) подано обидва варіанти:

> **ЖАРИТИ**, рю, риш, недок.
>
> 1. перех. Готувати їжу з жиром на вогні, на жару без використання води; ***смажити***.
>
> **СМАЖИТИ**, жу, жиш, недок.
>
> 1. перех. і без додатка. Готувати їжу (м'ясо, рибу і т. ін.) перев. із жиром на вогні, на жару без використання води; ***жарити***.

То чи справді нормативним є використання слова "жарити"? Чи не буде це калькою з російської, адже російсько-український словник подає відповідник "смажити"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) знайшла інформацію, що :

> ПЕКТИ́ (надмірно гріти, обдавати жаром); ПАЛИ́ТИ, ПРОПІКА́ТИ, **ЖА́РИТИ**розм., **СМА́ЖИТИ**розм
>   **СМА́ЖИТИ** (готувати м’ясо, рибу, овочі тощо на вогні без застосування води), **ЖА́РИТИ**, ШКВА́РИТИ, ПРЯГТИ́, ПРЯ́ЖИТИ[ПРА́ЖИТИ], ЗАСМА́ЖУВАТИ, ЗАЖА́РЮВАТИ (перев. окремою тушкою, великим шматком)

[Антисуржик](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244) подає  український відповідник:

> **жарений – смажений**

Отже,  можна зробити висновок, що залежно від значення(сонце **жарить**- ненормативно, АЛЕ **жарити**, смажити рибу –нормативно).

Той самий [Академічний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/zharyty) підтверджує цей висновок:
**ЖАРИТИ,** рю, риш, недок.

> //  **розм**. Підпікати кого-, що-небудь на вогні, на жару. Панів за те там мордовали [мордували] І жарили зо всіх боків. Що людям льготи не давали І ставили їх за скотів (Іван Котляревський, I, 1952, 135); Усюди картинки.., сам дідько з превеликими рогами — жарив грішні душі в смолі (Марко Вовчок, VI, 1956, 244).
>
> 2. неперех., **розм.** Сильно гріти, пригрівати; пекти, палити (про сонце).

Отже, ці два слова, залежно від значення, **нормативно** вживати.